# google playstore app reject (READ_CALL_LOG Permission)

Tags: android-permissions, google-play-console

I submitted my app to the Google Play Store console, but it was rejected for this reason.

Source inside Android.Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS"/>
```

In the Google Play Store console, in the App Contents section
Added READ_CALL_LOG to SMS and call log permission
I checked Caller ID, Detect and Block Spam.

I wonder why my app keeps getting rejected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8t4t.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5x1Y.png)

Added permission in app contents. to google playstore console.
It continues to be rejected on the Google Play Store with the same content.

Google's Reply =>
Issue with your app
After reviewing your app, we found that it doesn’t comply with the Permissions and APIs that Access Sensitive Information policy. An app can use Call Log or SMS permissions only when it is acting as a designated default handler or its core functionality falls within a permitted use case.
Your app appears to have an invalid exception use case declaration.
You declared that your app requires Caller ID, spam detection, and/or spam blocking as a core functionality, but we couldn’t verify this.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make sure you update the permissions and upload the new OBB file. I also got same issues for this [App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wFishingCarnival_17227635). Try to do the above. Thanks